# RoR filter on controller as this SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action-filter

How to write filter on the controller in Ruby on Rails, that is eqvivalent to this SQL code

```
select * from persons where persons.category = 'developers'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
before_filter :nerds_only

private

def nerds_only
  @people = Person.where(:category => 'developers')
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider creating a named scope to get the nerdies:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :developers, where(category: 'developers')
end
```

In your controller:

```
before_filter :developers_only

private

def developers_only
  @people = Person.developers
end
```